# Irrationality of $\pi$ isn't confirmed?

Tags: number-theory

I've heard that there is a bit of argument over whether you can confirm that $\pi$ is truly irrational. We know $\pi$ up to 2.7 trillion digits, but that accuracy isn't even that big, especially when you compare it to how accurately we know $e$. So, is there a possibility that the digits of $\pi$ will repeat or end?

Comment: $\pi$ is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) to be irrational.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The premise of the question is wrong, but that goes straight to the purpose of the question. The OP doesn't know!

Comment: @MattSamuel I guess it's related to the fact that a brief search on the internet would be sufficient for the OP to find out by himself.

Comment: @rafa I bet the same search will also get you some wrong info.

Comment: By the way, $\pi$ has been calculated far more accurate than $e$. Irrationality proofs are extremely difficult in general, for example it is unknown whether the Euler-Mascheroni-constant is rational.

Answer (score 10):

You can't prove irrationality by calculating digits and looking for a repeat because the repeat could start a little further out.  $\pi$ and $e$ are known to be transcendental, not just irrational.  You may have heard that we don't know if $\pi$ is normal, meaning any sequence of digits occurs with the correct limiting probability.  That is correct, but most people who understand it would guess that it is.